# How to install Doctrine in Linux (Ubuntu) through Terminal

Tags: php

Can any one explain the step by step procedure of installing Doctrine in Linux through terminal?

Comment: Do you want to have Doctrine in your global PHP include path or just inside of an project? Information please!

Comment: @Hikaru-Shindo , I want to have in my zend framework application , which is named square

Answer (score 0):

You can add doctrine to composer.json in your project directory

under require add "doctrine/common": "2.x"

```json
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
    "doctrine/common": "2.x" 
}
```

Then in your project directory run php composer.phar update

Comment: i also found a better way :) aka step by step version of the installment

Comment: http://samminds.com/2012/07/install-doctrine-2-for-zend-framework-2/

Comment: According to the tags he is using ZF1

Comment: @Ponsjuh , I cannot locate the composer.json in my directory

Comment: in case of zf1 use this http://www.spiffyjr.me/2010/11/17/zend-framework-1-11-doctrine-2-lets-play-nice-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate Doctrine 2 in a ZF1 project you may use the [Bisna Doctrine2 enabled ZF1 skeleton project from Github](https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/zendframework1-doctrine2)

Since you are trying to integrate Doctrine 2 your project does not seem to be really far into development so it should be easy to integrate.
The readme file explains the steps needed to be done quiet well.